# SQL-Server: Cannot be overwritten. It is being used by database

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

```
RESTORE DATABASE Tes
FROM DISK = '{7522204E-0256-47B3-9864-137D6D1FD449}6' 
WITH MOVE 'Test' TO 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Tes.mdf',
MOVE 'Test_log' TO 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Tes.ldf'
```

The above restore command is working fine  for new dbs, But few old  databases  it showing a errors like

> The file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\db1.mdf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database 'windb'.
>   Msg 3156, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   File 'windb' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\db1.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file

I found that only  dbs having more than one ndf files having this issues ..

Any solutions this issue ?

Comment: The error message is giving you the answer here. The file is **in use**. You can't overwrite a file that is currently in use, as you won't have write permissions (You're trying to restore the database using file names that are being used already). Like the error says, you'll need to use `WITH MOVE` and call the files something else, or `DROP` or Detach and move the existing databases first.

Answer (score 31):

Try to restore the database from the **Restore Database** Wizard. For that, in the **Object Explorer**, right-click on **Databases** -> select **Restore Databases...**. In the window that appears, set the necessary details for the *Source* and the *Destination*. And in the left pane, either select **Options** or **Files**, depending on the SSMS version you have.

In the table that appears, find the column **Restore As**. In each row, give a new file name, instead of the name that shows. For example, in your case it might be showing the file names as something similar to `<Folder Path>\DATA\Tes.mdf` and `<Folder Path>\DATA\Tes.ldf`. Give a different name other than *Tes*. (A name that does not already exist in the DATA folder).

**Note:** The file names do not have anything to do with the database name, but it will easy referencing later on to give a meaningful name, in case you have to backup or look for the files.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue when working on an MS SQL Server 2012.

I was trying to restore a database using the script below

```
USE master;
GO

ALTER DATABASE my_db SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

    
RESTORE DATABASE my_db.dev
    FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\com.mydb.dev.bak'
    WITH REPLACE,
         STATS = 10,
         RESTART,
    MOVE 'com.mydb.dev' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\com.mydb.dev.mdf',
    MOVE 'com.mydb.dev_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\com.mydb.dev_log.ldf'
GO
    
ALTER DATABASE com.mydb.dev SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

And then this was throwing the error below when I tried executing the restore task:

```
The file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\com.mydb.dev.mdf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database restdb

The file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\com.mydb.dev_log.ldf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database restdb
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was that the database backup file that I was using for this database restore operation had been previously used to restore data to a different database on the same server.

All I had to do was to change the Physical names of the Logical files to that of the database that I was to restore to. That is from `com.mydb.dev.mdf` to `my_db.mdf` and from `com.mydb.dev_log.ldf` to `my_db_log.ldf`:

```
USE master;
GO

ALTER DATABASE my_db SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

    
RESTORE DATABASE my_db
    FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\com.mydb.dev.bak'
    WITH REPLACE,
         STATS = 10,
         RESTART,
    MOVE 'com.my_db.dev' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\my_db.mdf',
    MOVE 'com.mydb.dev_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\my_db_log.ldf'
GO
    
ALTER DATABASE my_db SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

And this time, the database restore task ran successfully.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to move your database to a new location, you should better detach the source database or take it offline first